# Since updating to 16.04 many application are missing the file menu

Tags: upgrade, 16.04

I just upgraded to 16.04 and I noticed there are a number of apps where the file menu is no longer being shown.
Sublime text, Filezilla, LibreOffice, MySql Workbench are just a few examples(I'm sure there are others but those are the main ones I've noticed so far) Other apps it appears to be fine, like Chrome.  I can access most of the menus by pressing alt + f but it's still a bit annoying that the menu is not displayed at all on a number of apps. Is there anything I can try to get them back?

Comment: This is a bug. It has been fixed for most cases. Update your system. Also `unity` command in terminal should fix it till reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem can be in menus setting. Try to open **System Settings** by typing `unity-control-center` in terminal, there click on **Appearance**, choose **Behavior** and here is setting "**Show the menus for a window**". Here choose second: **In the window's title bar**.